# Stripe retrieving all subscriptions is empty

Tags: php, stripe-payments

As you can see in the image below, I have 1 subscription active in my Stripe Test environment.
[image]

But when I try to retrieve this subscription through the endpoint `GET /v1/subscriptions` it comes empty.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
$list = $stripe->subscriptions->all();
print_r($list);
```

The result:

```
Stripe\Collection Object
(
    [object] => list
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

    [has_more] => 
    [url] => /v1/subscriptions
)
```

I have double checked and I'm using the test keys.

Also, if I try to retrieve the single subscription using the endpoint `GET /v1/subscriptions/:id`:

```
$stripe->subscriptions->retrieve('sub_....', []);
```

It returns the error:

> No such subscription 'sub_.....'

And the ID is totally correct (just copied and paste from Stripe dashboard).

Comment: May be you mix up TEST_ MODE with PROD_MODE?

Comment: @Ivan negative, as you can see in the printscreen, I'm with TEST Mode active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot retrieve the subscription directly by ID, you are likely mixing up keys from a different account. Double check the account you're logged in to and which account the keys belong to and try again.